# Quick questions. I'm having issues with my "While" loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, exit

I'm running into an annoying problem. The issue I'm running into is; when I enter -1 in the first `cin >> statement` the while does not exit like I want it to.

I'm trying not to use `"break"` in the loop because I've been told its a bad habit.

FYI moveOn is initialized to true.
Here is the code:

```
while(moveOn){

cout << "Enter info:";
cin >> weight;
if(weight == -1){
    moveOn = false;
}

weight = pack.weight;
cin >> pack.sides[0] >> pack.sides[1] >> pack.sides[2];

    while(pack.weight > 0 || pack.sides[0] < 0 || pack.sides[1] < 0 || pack.sides[2] < 0){
        cout << "Enter Vaild info:";
        cin >> pack.weight >> pack.sides[0] >> pack.sides[1] >> pack.sides[2];
    }

girth = getGirth(pack.sides);
float price;
price = getPackageAmount(pack.weight, weights, prices);
cout << price << endl;

if( pack.weight <= 50){
    if(pack.sides[0] <= 36 && pack.sides[1] <= 36 && pack.sides[2] <= 36){
        if(girth <= 60){
            pack.accepted = true;
            accepted++;
        }
    }
}
else{
    pack.accepted = false;
    rejected++;

}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `continue;` or `else` clause.

Comment: `weight = pack.weight;` should probably be `pack.weight = weight;`. That's probably why this isn't working.

Comment: "the while does not exit like I want it to" -- how exactly is that? do you want it to `break` immediately? because, if so, you still have all those statements below that are going to be executed, in which case you could follow @MikeCAT 's advice.

Comment: Kind of works. Where would be the best place to put the continue statement to end the loop?

Comment: Just after `moveOn = false;`

Comment: Got it working, Thanks all!

Comment: Do you think this title will be useful in a list of questions?

Answer (score 3):

`while(moveOn)` does not mean "stop immediately when `moveOn` becomes `false`" - the test is only performed at the start of each iteration of the loop.

You need to add an `else` clause:

```
while (moveOn)
{
    cout << "Enter info:";
    cin >> weight;
    if(weight == -1){
        moveOn = false;
    }
    else
    {
        weight = pack.weight;
        // ...
    }
}
```

(You probably also want to change `weight = pack.weight` to `pack.weight = weight`.)

Comment: So basically throw the rest of the code into the else statement? Correct me if I'm not understanding you correctly.

Comment: @MichaelCorbett Exactly. (I personally think that a `break` is perfectly fine and more readable in this case, though.)

Comment: I would normally agree with you! However, the professor doesn't like break statements so I'm stuck not being able to use them.

Comment: @MichaelCorbett Yeah, professors can be like that. It's common in learning: first you get hard rules in order to avoid getting into bad habits (and endless arguments), then you learn when those rules should be broken. At least if you're lucky ;-)